# Limit of an union of open interval

Tags: real-analysis

Could you please suggest a sketch of the proof of this problem:

> Prove:
>
> 1. $(a;b) = \bigcup \limits_{k = 1}^{\infty} (a;b- \frac{1}{k}$]
> 2. $(-\infty; b) = \bigcup \limits_{k = 1}^{\infty} (-k; b- \frac{1}{k}$]

I just can't make up my mind with the limit of an interval ($i.e.$ when $k \to \infty$).

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\subseteq$, take a point $x \in (a,b)$. Choose $k$ such that $\frac1k < b-x$, then $x < b-\frac1k$ and hence $x \in (a;b-\frac1k]$. The second exercise is similar.

For $\supseteq$, take a point $x \in \cup_{i = k}^\infty (a, b-\frac1k)$. Since $x$ is in a union of sets, it must be in at least one of those sets. Let $k$ be such that $x \in (a,b-\frac1k]$. Since $(a,b-\frac1k] \subset (a,b)$, it follows that $x \in (a,b)$.

Note that the statement also holds with open intervals on the Right Hand Side.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But could you please give a sketch for the $\supset$ direction. In fact, I think it is not trivial. And moreover, it should be $x \in (a; b - 1/k]$ right (with the ] rather than ")" )?

Comment: $(a;b-1/k)$ is a subset of $(a;b-1/k]$, so $x \in (a,b-1/k)$ implies $x \in (a;b-1/k]$. I'll edit the other direction into the post.